# Replace MNIST data in Tensorflow CNN models

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a CNN model on my own dataset in tensorflow. I transformed my data in the same MNIST format with this code https://github.com/gskielian/JPG-PNG-to-MNIST-NN-Format/blob/master/convert-images-to-mnist-format.py.

Now I don't know how to replace the MNIST data with my own data. Is there a way to replace mnist data with my own data or import them in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) file especially at the lines where the import of the mnist data is programmed.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data    
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
```

This function imports the mnist data. According to [the function's sourcecode](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py) (line 229 ff.) your files should have the following names so you need to rewrite the function you've linked to so there is a test set.

```
TRAIN_IMAGES = 'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TRAIN_LABELS = 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
TEST_IMAGES = 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TEST_LABELS = 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
```

Alternatively you could adapt the function's source to your needs and write your own import function.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote my function in order to have the same names. But I don't still know how read my data. In Tensorflow tutorials data are automatically loaded (like in the mnist_softmax.py code you linked), so I don't Know how read these IDX1-UBYTE files.

Comment: When you just want to read the files for the training as is done in the tutorial's function, you can use the data like it is used in mnist_softmax.py in line 65 and 71/72. If you want to read these files with a function you want to write yourself from scratch I have to admit, that I can't help you with that.